# Как открыть xml файл в браузере

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть xml и xslt файлы, хочу открыть xml файл в браузере(не важно будь то Google или Edge), но почему-то не получается нужна помощь[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: xsl файлик]

Когда пытаюсь открыть вылазит пустая страница
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Как думаете, какой шаблон срабатывает первым: `match="/"` или `match="hiblock"`?

Comment: Задавая вопрос XSLT, вам необходимо предоставить [минимальный воспроизводимый пример] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Входной XML.
(2) Ваша логика и XSLT, который пытается ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат, основанный на образце XML в #1 выше.
(4) Процессор XSLT и его соответствие стандартам XSLT: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 или 4.0.
Все в вопросе в виде текста, без скриншотов.